# Чи є в українській мові слово «знайоммось» (у значенні: «давайте знайомитися»)?

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання, наказовий-спосіб

Чи це все таки [defective verb](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/393/4), що не має наказового способу множини?

З одного боку, вжитки є:

1. Якісь «народні» словники: [uk.oldict](//uk.oldict.com/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8/), [slovnyk.ua](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F).
2. На сайті ГО «Вольниця»: [1](http://volnytsia.org/10176/), [2](http://volnytsia.org/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F-shared-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE-53/).
3. В Google Books: [Віктор Міняйло «Посланець до живих» (1966)](//books.google.com/books?id=Z13qAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22).

З іншого боку, це майже єдині вжитки. (Хоча дивився лише «знайоммось». «Познайоммось», «познайоммо», «знайоммо» і таке інше не дивився.)

Comment: На "знайоммося" трохи більше [результатів](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=TtDLWJpj76_zB-LJnrAF#tbs=li:1&q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F&*). Подейкують, що українська мова тяжіє до відкритих складів - варто шукати з "ся".

Comment: @Sasha, ось знайшла ще тут: [WorldwideDictionary.org](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F). **Наказовий спосіб: 1 особа - знайо́ммося, знайо́ммось.** Втім, це, напевно, таке ж джерело, як і "народні словники".

Answer (score 7):

Є три особи, для яких можна утоврити наказовий спосіб дієслова (з [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1)):

> Дієслова наказового способу не мають форм часу, але вони змінюються за особами в однині і множині. В **однині** вони мають форму 2-ї особи, а в **множині** — 1-ї і 2-ї.

Тож ваше питання стосується саме форми 1-ї особи множини.

Оскільки в цьому випадку заклик формально стосується як мовця, так і адресата, то часто замість відповідної форми дієслова [вживається](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1/) частка "нумо" + форма інфінітиву: "нумо знайомитись".

Comment: Тобто є повністю літературний еквіватент — «нумо знайомитись». Це добре. Але все ж цікаво, наскільки «знайоммось» нормативний.

Comment: Зауважу, частка «нумо» стилістично маркована й передає дещо інший відтінок, тому механічна заміна наказової форми на «нумо» може бути небажаною. Порівняйте: «намалюймо дві квіточки» та «нумо малювати дві квіточки».